# Why module go to vendor directory if install using composer Magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, composer, vendor

Can anyone please tell me the reason why module go to Vendor directory when install using composer?

Please refer me a link for this reason.

In my custom extension, I am using this code in my composer file.

```
{

"name": "vendor/module",
"description": "Magento 2 Shipping Rates",
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": [
"OSL-3.0",
"AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {},
"authors": [
{
  "name": "ABC",
  "email": "abc@mail.com",
  "homepage": "abc.com",
  "role": "Owner"
}
],
"autoload": {
"files": [ "registration.php" ],
"psr-4": {
  "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
}
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true 
}
```

Also, I have configured Github and Packagist too.

But when I try to install my module using composer by using command

> composer require vendor/module

I am getting this error message.

> ```
> ./composer.json has been updated
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>     - The requested package vendor/module * is satisfiable by vendor/module[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
> ```

Comment: Have you tried installing this module on a clean Magento 2 install? Might be conflicting with existing code if you've got it stored in app/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your github account have you pushed to master? Also what if you add a tag in git with label 1.0.0 and then push tag to master and for example and then try to do the following from within magento

`composer require vendor/module:1.0.0`

Comment: Thanks this work for me :)

Comment: But can you please provide a link to tell me the reason why module go to Vendor directory when install using composer?

Comment: It's just how composer works https://igor.io/2013/09/04/composer-vendor-directory.html